# NullPointerException with ViewPager

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewpager

My app accesses a webservice. I put in a search term and the app returns a list of articles relating to the search term i use. These articles are presented in listview.  something very strange is happening and I have no idea what is going wrong.  My app works perfectly when entering any search term.  However, when i enter a very specific search term " ebola", a result returns, and is displayed in listview. However, when i click on an item in the listview, my app crashes.  This only happens for this very specific search term and no other.  It is really frustrating as my code obviously works but for some unknown reason not for this very particular search term.

StackTrace:

```
    02-03 10:24:51.286  31560-31560/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/dalvikvm﹕  threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41611d40)
    02-03 10:24:51.288  31560-31560/com.example.lifesci_pubmed E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lifesci_pubmed, PID: 31560
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lifesci_pubmed/com.android.lifesci_pubmed.ArticlePagerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.ArticlePagerActivity.onCreate(ArticlePagerActivity.java:66)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The piece of code that is quoted as being responsible for the nullpointException:

```
 String title = (String)  getIntent().getStringExtra(ArticleFragment.EXTRA_TITLE);
for (int i = 0; i < articles.size(); i++) {
    if (articles.get(i).getTitle().equals(title)) {  // this line here
        myViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
```

Comment: `articles.get(i)` or `artiles.get(i).getTitle()` is `null`. Consider using a debugger to find out what and why. `articles` is not null since you managed to call `size()` on it.

Comment: Using  system logs I found that articles.get(i) is not null (returns a value).articles.get(i).getTitle() is not null (returns a value). And articles.get(i).getTitle().Equals(title) returns true.  I am still getting a NullpointerException Error for this particular search term.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think **articles.get(i).getTitle() returning null**! Please provide the json you are receiving from the backend. Check for **jsonException** as well.

Comment: This is not an answer, instead it should be a comment.